# Lyle's vocal delivery

Tags: casting, napoleon-dynamite

The character of Lyle in Napoleon Dynamite is an old farmer and also a local minister with a vocal delivery that is something between a speech impediment and an extreme redneck mumbling.  I am just curious if the actor who played him actually acted that vocal delivery out or does the guy really talk like that in real life.

Comment: You could watch the other film he's in to see if he speaks the same way in it: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0457303/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_1

Answer (score 3):

The movie was filmed in Preston, ID and this man is a local who has acted in several films from Mormon film makers.  I have a number of friends from Preston who know him and have told me that this is how he talks, although I believe it was somewhat exaggerated for this film.

Answer (score 2):

I am from Preston Idaho and helped Mr Critchlow run his farm for several years.  What you see in the film is pure Dale Critchlow.

Comment: do you have any evidence to back this claim?